# Where is the positive on this trimmer capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

[image: image of trimmer capacitor upside down.]

Hello, I'm trying to make project 11 in Dick Smith's book "Funway into Electronics 2." I'm making it on a breadboard because I don't have a kit.

I am struggling to find out where the positive is on the trimmer capacitor.

Comment: Connect your multi-meter up to it and find out what rotation direction corresponds with what resistance change. Not that it really matters in how you wire it up since resistors aren't polarized.

Comment: @DKNguyen:  Trimmer **capacitors** don't usually register anything reasonable on an ohmmeter...

Comment: @JRE Oh it's a capacitor. Didn't notice that, and I doubt the OP has an LCR meter. Either way, not polarized so stick it into the circuit in any direction and turn it to find out.

Comment: trimmers “May” have < 1pF more stray capacitance on one lead vs the other. Inspection of part or datasheet may tell, which is which but probably won’t matter since it can be “trimmed”. (Lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trimmer capacitors and low value fixed capacitors are not polarized, so won't have a "positive" indication.